# Cells not named in Excel sheets but still the Data from Cells need to be taken

Tags: delphi, excel, excel-2003

I have an Excel 2003 sheets being used by clients.

I need to update a Delphi application that extracts data from these cells, but the cells are not named at all, they are just `j3` and `j55`.

Can the data from cells still be sent across to other applications?

Can Delphi application take these values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can process Excel files through Delphi using OLE.

```
uses
  ComObj;

procedure TForm3.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ExcelApp: OleVariant;
begin    
  try    
      ExcelApp := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
      if not VarIsEmpty(ExcelApp) then
      Begin
       ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open('c:\yourfile.xls'); //Open File
       ShowMessage(ExcelApp.Range['J55', 'J55'].Value);   //Extract value from Cell J55
      End;    

  finally

    if not VarIsEmpty(ExcelApp) then
    begin
      ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts := False;
      ExcelApp.Quit;
    end;

  end;

end;
```

Bye.

Comment: A good way to "work out" what is needed is to record a macro in Excel, then translate the macro code from VBA to Delphi

Answer (score -1):

Sure, why not?

You could use Excel Object Model & use the series of classes to access the contents of the cell.

VB(script) example

```
dim xlApp
set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

dim wkBook
set wkBook = xlApp.WorkBooks.Add

dim wkSheet
set wkSheet = wkBook.Sheets(1)

dim cell
set cell = wkSheet.Cells("A1")  'get the reference to cell A1

msgbox cell.Value
```

The best way to learn about Excel object model is to
1. Open Excel
2. Press ALT + F11 (VBA editor)
3. Press F2 (for object browser)
4. Choose Excel from the dropdown where it shows

The root class is Application & then things flow from there.
e.g. WorkBook -> WorkSheets -> Worksheet -> Cells (Range) etc.

Hope that helps.